# OSX: Spotlight shows the content of locked notes

Tags: macos, spotlight

When I search in the spotlight for a locked note, I can see the content of that looked note. I went ahead and rebuilt the spotlight index, but still showing the content. Am I missing something here or is it a bug? OSX-ELCapitan 10.11.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to close your notes**

[image]

I justed tested this in OS 10.11.5 and the contents of the note don't show, just the title.

I created a note and titled it for which it would be easy for Spotlight to find:  "Smattering test note"  (I have no other instance of "Smattering" on my system).  Here is what it looks like after I have *locked* and *closed* the note.

[image]

Doing a Spotlight search for "Smattering" yields this result:

[image]

It autocompletes the note title (ligher grey text) and clicking on it opens the Notes App.  Until I unlock the note with my password, the contents are not visible.

**If I don't *lock and close* my notes, if I do a Spotlight search, the contents will be visible**

Comment: Thank you for the details. So I see what the issue is, I went ahead and renamed the existing locked note, but the spotlight is still showing the old version of the locked note that doesn't exist in notes anymore. It seems that I have duplicate of old notes somewhere and even if I lock it, it will show the other old version. Where can I find them?

Comment: When you do a spotlight search, look at the very bottom of the left column of sources.  Click on "Show All in Finder".  It will bring them up for you

Comment: Thank you a bunch! Here is the path in case some is having the same issue
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/CoreData/ExternalRecords/HTMLNotes/40943718-ADA7-487A-8194-7FE94D6460DC/IMAPNote/_records/2/0